# Diamond inheritance with mixed inheritance modifers (protected / private / public)

Tags: c++, inheritance, diamond-problem

let's say we have `class A,B,C,D` where A is base, B,C are between and D is derived in diamond model.

*NOTE:*

`class B` inherits virtualy `class A` in **private** mode,

`class C` inherita virtualy `class A` in **protected** mode.

```
class A
{
public:
    int member;  // note this member
};
class B :
    virtual private A // note private 
{

};
class C :
    virtual protected A // note protected
{

};
class D :
    public B, // doesn't metter public or whatever here
    public C
{

};

int main()
{
    D test;
    test.member = 0; // WHAT IS member? protected or private member?
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

now when we make an instance of `class D` what will member be then? private or protected lol?

**Figure No2:**

what if we make it so:

```
class B :
    virtual public A // note public this time!
{

};
class C :
    virtual protected A // same as before
{

};
```

I suppose `member` will be public in this second example isn it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`§11.6 Multiple access [class.paths]`

> If a name can be reached by several paths through a multiple inheritance graph, **the access is that of the path that gives most access**. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> class W { public: void f(); };
> class A : private virtual W { };
> class B : public virtual W { };
> class C : public A, public B {
>    void f() { W::f(); } // OK
> };
> ```
>
> Since `W::f()` is available to `C::f()` along the public path through `B`, access is allowed. *—end example* ]

I think I don't need to add anything else, but see also [this defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#471) (which was closed as "not a defect").

Comment: @Kerrek: Thanks for the edit, I couldn't remember how to seamlessly embed code in a quote. :)

Comment: That was I saying im my previous comment :D public has more "power" then private or protected. nice example thanks alot. but this is not the case with PRIVATE/PROTECTED combination! inheritance list has more power in that case :) cool.

Comment: @codekiddy: I don't quite understand. If the example was changed from `public virtual/private virtual` to `protected virtual/private virtual`, the behaviour would still be the same - the call to `W::f()` would be allowed because of the protected access path through `B` - the order in the inheritance list (base-class list) has nothing to do with anything as far as I can see.

Comment: Oh sory, I was talking aobut calling function f() from an instance of object C (in your example) in functio main! not calling inside a class like W::F() :D call it from an instance and you'll see hehe

Comment: ADD: remove funciton f() {(W::f(); } and the call it from an instance of C or copy my first example!

Comment: @codekiddy: Well, of course. The most accessible path is `protected`, and you can't call protected stuff outside of the inheritence hierarchy.

Comment: @Xeo, Visual studio says: "can't acces protected member" then if I swap inheritance list it say's "can't access private member". as you said that compiler does not implement those rules corectly :(